# Como mostrar o valor do jQuery UI Slider em um input de texto e atualizar o Slider se um valor for inserido no input de texto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, formulário, jquery-ui

O resultado que preciso atingir usando o jQuery UI Slider parece ser simples. O Slider será utilizado para definir a idade do usuário que submeteria o formulário, com valor mínimo de 18 (anos) e máximo 100 (anos)... O objetivo pretendido pode ser dividido em duas partes:

**Primeira parte** > Mostrar o valor do Slider em um input de texto:

Até aqui, eu consigo que a primeira parte do objetivo funcione normalmente com o seguinte código. O resultado pode ser visto [aqui no jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/plan/GGRXP/1/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $("#slider-idade").slider({
  range: "min",
  value: 18,
  min: 18,
  max: 100,
  step: 1,
  animate: 200,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
 $("#valor-idade").val(ui.value);
}
 });

 $("#valor-idade").val($("#slider-idade").slider("value"));
});
```

**Segunda parte > Atualizar o Slider caso o usuário insira um valor no input de texto:**

------//------

Tentei seguir algumas instruções e soluções postadas no stackoverflow em inglês, tal como podemos ver nesse stack aqui https://stackoverflow.com/a/7524385/1152876, contudo, não estou conseguindo implementar as soluções propostas na discussão.

*Apenas para constar, caso haja alguma interferência: No site que estou implementando o Slider, estou utilizando também o jQuery UI Touch Punch https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch#readme para adicionar suporte a eventos Touch à biblioteca do jQuery UI quando usada em dispositivos móveis, já que por padrão a biblioteca jquery-ui não funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falta apenas colocar um evento para monitorar quando o campo de texto teve o valor alterado, e atualizar o slider com esse valor:

```
$("#valor-idade").change(function(){
    $("#slider-idade").slider("value", this.value);
});
```

<sup>[Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7Z5q/)</sup>

Comment: Perfeito, @bfavaretto - Funciona!  Acabei identificando o problema real: Havia um conflito com outra porção de código jQuery dado a maneira como eu estava inicializando o Slider. De qualquer forma, ótima solução. Dei meu voto!

Comment: Me deparei agora com um pequeno impasse: Quando eu insiro um valor no input de texto, o meu formulário criado com o plugin WPCF7 (Contact Form 7) é submetido dado a natureza do plugin. Você saberia como evitar que isso aconteça usando jQuery? Penso se seria possível identificar o input de texto por id ou classe e restringir que o evento keypress efetuado neste input submeta o formulário?

Comment: Ele submete se teclar enter, ou ao simplesmente colocar qualquer valor no campo?

Comment: Ele submete o form apenas ao pressionar a tecla enter, quando o foco está no input de texto, aliás, com o código em questão, o Slider só é atualizado ao apertar enter...mas como estou testando no ambiente de produção, vejo que teria que usar js para contornar o script do Contact Form 7... O formulário pode ser visto no site aqui: http://goo.gl/bkrjRZ

Comment: Seria melhor eu criar uma nova pergunta? Sou novo na comunidade...qual a melhor prática nessas horas? se importa em me informar?

Comment: @Monecchi Acho que vale a pena sim uma pergunta à parte para isso. Mas olhei seu site e vi que realmente o slider não atualiza quando o campo simplesmente perde o foco, mas deveria, como ocorre no meu exemplo no jsfiddle. Você já aplicou o código da minha resposta?

Comment: Sim, é exatamente o mesmo código da sua resposta, sem alterações. Eu também estou utilizando um código para limpar os vários tipos inputs no site quando em foco. Atualizei o seu código no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plan/X7Z5q/1/) com o código que uso pra limpar os campos, mas não vejo conflito algum. Acredito ser mesmo o javascript do próprio plugin, no caso o Contact Form 7. Nesse stack em inglês http://stackoverflow.com/a/11235672/1152876, a discussão parece ser promissora, vou tentar as soluções propostas por lá...

Comment: Sim @Monecchi, a solução é exatamente essa que você linkou. Mas se tiver paciência, vale a pena criar a pergunta aqui. Pode até responder você mesmo, isso é incentivado no site. É uma pergunta comum, e seria legal termos aqui uma resposta para futuros visitantes com a mesma dúvida.